# How to change an Image in a Setter Value in Windows Phone programatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-8.1, resourcedictionary

I have a resource defined in a resource dictionary that looks like this:

```
<x:Int32 x:Key="HubSectionHeaderCharacterSpacing">-10</x:Int32>
<x:Double x:Key="HubSectionHeaderFontSize">19</x:Double>
<Thickness x:Key="HubSectionHeaderMarginThickness">-1,5,0,31.5</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="HubSectionMarginThickness">19,0,0,0</Thickness>
<Style x:Key="MainMenuHubSectionStyle2" TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HubSection">
                <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="WrappingTransform"/>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Logos/Logo.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I have a HubSection that uses this style. How to programatically access this resource and replace the

```
<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Logos/Logo.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Viewbox>
```

with some other image?

Comment: Why you cant just bind to string property and change it in runtime?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do this thing. I am not using MVVM, so where to put this string property (and of what type should it be, "ImageSource" ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a dirty hack, but since you have only one property to replace, you can take advantage of the `Tag` property to store your image url:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuHubSectionStyle2" TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HubSection">
                <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="WrappingTransform"/>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<HubSection Tag="ms-appx:///Assets/Logos/Logo.png">
</HubSection>
```

Otherwise, you probably would have to make your own type, inheriting from HubSection and adding the necessary properties.

Alternatively, you could use good ol' databinding, as suggested by RenDishen. For instance:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuHubSectionStyle2" TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HubSection">
                <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="WrappingTransform"/>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Logo}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you would have to assign to the `DataContext` property of your HubSection an object that has a `Logo` property, and fill it accordingly.